# Intersect analysis with a filter on attributes

Tags: arcpy, intersection

I'm trying to do an intersect analysis,

```
# Intersect(in_features, out_feature_class, {join_attributes}, {cluster_tolerance}, {output_type})
arcpy.Intersect_analysis(layer1, output)
```

but I can't see how to further refine the analysis based on attributes?

layer 1 is events, and being compared against a layer of maintenance activities. When maintenance activities are finished, they are no longer relevant. So how do I want to find intersections between the two layers, where `status of maintenance <> 'complete'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management`](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/make-feature-layer.htm) with a `where_clause`.

If you do this before you intersect, your intersect should be quicker as there's less data to process

Comment: And a more complex criteria? Lets say `events` and `maintenance` have a start date and end date. Anything happening in the same location more than a year apart, is not an intersection. Both input feature class or layer have start date / end data attributes.

Comment: https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/working-with-layers/sql-reference-for-query-expressions-used-in-arcgis.htm

Comment: yep, I see that. But I cannot see how to say the equivalent in SQL of `startdate of any two items within 12 months of another item`

Comment: I would if I could. Guess I'll have to wait until next week.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server has this native capability in the STOverlaps function. No python needed

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/stoverlaps-geometry-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15

```
SELECT top 10
  a.Column1 as 'Column1Name',
  a.Column2 as 'Column2Name',
  a.Start_Date as 'aStartDate',
  a.End_Date as 'aEndDate'
  b.Start_Date as 'bStartDate',
  b.End_Date as 'bEndDate'

FROM 
    tablename a
    inner join tablename b 
    on a.SHAPE.STOverlaps(b.SHAPE) = 1

WHERE 
    aStartDate between bStartDate and bEndDate
```